# AngularJS: Loading single objects from json

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to list some posts from a json file then after click one, load the single post, but when I click it the data is not loaded.

I'm using the function below to handle the data

```
$scope.currentPost = $filter('filter')($scope.posts, {id: $routeParams.id})
```

Here is my Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/brWn6r4UvLnNY5gcFF2X?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/3P2k60aPyuatjTx9raJU?p=preview

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, $route, $routeParams, $filter) {
  $scope.name = 'Test';

  $scope.getData = function(){
    $http.get('posts.json')
      .then(function(res){
          $scope.posts = res.data.posts;
          $scope.currentPost = $filter('filter')($scope.posts, {id: $routeParams.id});
          $scope.currentPost = $scope.currentPost[0]; // $filter apparently returns an array...
        });
  };
  // setInterval($scope.getData, 1000); // DO WE REALLY NEED IT?

  $scope.getData();

});
```

---

Alternative solution using `_` *(underscore)* `findWhere` method:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, $route, $routeParams, $filter) {
  $scope.name = 'Test';

  $scope.getData = function(){
    $http.get('posts.json')
      .then(function(res){
          $scope.posts = res.data.posts;
          // id: integer
          // $routeParams.id: string
          // when comparing integer to string _.findWhere was failing
          // always good practice to pass radix to parseInt: http://davidwalsh.name/parseint-radix
          $scope.currentPost = _.findWhere($scope.posts,  {id: parseInt($routeParams.id, 10)});
        });
  };
  // setInterval($scope.getData, 1000); // DO WE REALLY NEED IT?

  $scope.getData();

});
```

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/N7UeaOuoNIoQgzQfrkY3?p=preview

In my code I usually use `_` but now I've learnt something new - I can use `$filter` too!

Comment: It works! Thanks! But apparently there is a delay with a previous data loaded. There is some way to clear the previous data before load the view?

Comment: *"there is a delay"*... I think it might be related to making ```GET``` request to ```post.html``` (loading partials over the wire)